# asp.net fileupload control, uploading file to ftp

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ftp

I'm trying upload a file via asp.net forms. Problem is when i use FileUpload control to get path to the file a got just name of file, not full path. And to upload a file to ftp i need a full path. Can i achieve this somehow ?

form code:

```
<div align="center">
            <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" Width="600px" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
</div>
```

button click code:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(FileUploadControl.FileName != null)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                //MessageBox.Show(this, Server.MapPath(FileUploadControl.FileName));


            var temp = ftp + ftpFolder + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);

            try
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(loginName, password);
                    client.UploadFile(temp, "STOR", FileUploadControl.FileName); // ???
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }

            }

        }
```

it's not nessesary to use FileUpload, but i need something where user can choose file from folder and it give me full path.

Comment: this day and age their are many examples already on stack that state how to do this google search brings up many examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx):

**Saving Uploaded Files**

> The FileUpload control does not automatically
>   save a file to the server after the user selects the file to upload.
>   You must explicitly provide a control or mechanism to allow the user
>   to submit the specified file. For example, you can provide a button
>   that the user clicks to upload the file. The code that you write to
>   save the specified file should call the SaveAs method, which saves the
>   contents of a file to a specified path on the server. Typically, the
>   SaveAs method is called in an event-handling method for an event that
>   raises a post back to the server. For example, if you provide a button
>   to submit a file, you could include the code to save the file inside
>   the event-handling method for the click event.

So, you are never really saving the file (not even uploading it). What you want is something like this:

```
static string yourSuperSecretDirectory = @"C:\ApplicationName\Uploads";
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        string filename = Path.Combine(yourSuperSecretDirectory, FileUploadControl.FileName);
        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(filename); //actually save/upload the file

        string temp = ftp + ftpFolder + filename

        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(loginName, password);
                client.UploadFile(temp, "STOR", FileUploadControl.FileName); // ???
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that's work. I just don't get, how can i miss this.